# Google App Engine Flask Error in 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' CORPS settings

Tags: python, facebook, google-app-engine, flask, google-app-engine-python

I am using Google App Engine and flask to get the authentication  from the Facebook
I have created the FB Application and it connects fine

I am  using the following libraries

- flask-cors==2.1.2
- flask-restful==0.3.5

I am setting CORS settings as follows

```
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/api/v1/*": {"origins": "*"}})
```

I am getting the following error

```
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&client_id=40400553…alhost%3A8080%2Fapi%2Fv1%2Fusers%2Ffacebook2%2F&scope=email&_external=True. Redirect from 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&client_id=40400553…alhost%3A8080%2Fapi%2Fv1%2Fusers%2Ffacebook2%2F&scope=email&_external=True' to 'https://www.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=404005532980775…_&display=page&locale=en_GB&logger_id=c25bd044-3438-4a9b-b9ef-3f1701bf1d1c' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Request Handler

```
SECRET_KEY = 'development key'
DEBUG = True
FACEBOOK_APP_ID = '40400553-----'
FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET = 'bc04c3c33f-----'

facebook_config = dict(
  access_token_url='/oauth/access_token',
  authorize_url='/oauth/authorize',
  base_url='https://graph.facebook.com/',
  consumer_key=FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
  consumer_secret=FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
  request_token_params={'scope': 'email'},
)

            def create_oauth_app(service_config, name):
              upper_name = name.upper()
              app.config[upper_name] = service_config
              service_oauth = oauth.OAuth()
              service_app = service_oauth.remote_app(name, app_key=upper_name)
              service_oauth.init_app(app)
              return service_app


          def signin_fb_oauth(oauthapp, scheme=None):
              try:
                flask.session.pop('oauth_token', None)
                save_request_params()
                print '****************************'
                print 'signin oauth'
                print '*******************************'
                #call_back_url_appengine = 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/facebook2/'
                call_back_url_flask= 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/facebook2/'
                fb_auth = oauthapp.authorize(
                  callback=call_back_url_flask,
                  _external=True
                )

                return  fb_auth
                  except oauth.OAuthException:
                  flask.flash(
                  'Something went wrong with sign in. Please try again.',
                  category='danger',
                )
                print '*******************************************'
                print 'Error in AuthenticationError'
                print '*******************************************'
                return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('signin',     next=util.get_next_url()))
```

This application has a Angualr2 front end and Flask Google App Engine Backend

What could possibly go wrong  here ?

[image]

Comment: Probably should show a little more of your code involved, including your request handlers.

Comment: @BrettJ Hi Brett , I have added more supportive code .

Comment: If I'm reading that right it looks like the error seems to imply its a CORs problem on the facebook side of things rather than on your side. Maybe the issue is on your client side code. Did you deploy this code to see if it behaved differently there?